# Script that prints style from google spreadsheet to google doc

Tags: google-apps-script

Please see my spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/a/zigmens.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AtXr7M_f8JAadG1qclprdXRFb3VuNXV0OXg5bDNpNkE&usp=drive_web#gid=0

I have a menu item, Create/Job Scope that pulls data from the spreadsheet and creates a new document in "my drive" location of google drive.  Problem I have, is that it's not including the stye and format that I have in the spreadsheet.  I have tried many ways of setting the variable in the script to "bold", for example, but can't seem to get it to work. I am hoping there is an object that I can add to the variable that will set it's style.

For example, in my script, I have a variable called "desc"

```
var descr = values[n][3] ;
```

I would like to just create a new variable such as

```
var descr = values[n][3] ;

var desc_style = descr.setStyle("bold") ;
```

Here is the script from the spreadsheet but I think it's best if you just update the script in my spreadsheet.

```
function jobScope() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var docTemplate = "19ANrZluvbavWU4Ttgh1z9_DVJgEQ1hrGohd4lQAg7vI";
  var job_name = ss.getRange("D4").getValue();
  var docName = job_name+' Job Scope '; 

  var x = 1 ;
  while(values[x][0] ^= "") {    
     ++x ;
  }
  var textToDoc = "" ;
  for(n=1;n<x;++n){  
     var cell = values[n][4] ; 
    if (cell ^ "0") {
      var line_item = values[n][1]; 
      var descr = values[n][3] ;
      textToDoc = textToDoc + line_item + "  " + descr + "\n\n" ;

    }

  }

  var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
  .makeCopy(docName)
  .getId();  

  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

  copyBody.replaceText('keyScope', textToDoc);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyJobName', job_name);

  copyDoc.saveAndClose();  

}
```

Comment: You need to also give permission for the document template (19ANrZluvbavWU4Ttgh1z9_DVJgEQ1hrGohd4lQAg7vI).  We need to be able to access that document to work with your script (giving a permission error since it's not set to public).

Comment: I made the document template public.  Sorry about the delay.  I expected an email notification, but I guess that didn't happen.  I hope someone can help me with this today.

Comment: I wonder if I need to use and html script so that I can use the html tags for styling the document.  So when I have the script editor open, should I create a new "html" file (File/New/HTML file).  Problem is I don't know how to go down this road...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the formatting of the keys to your preferred style?  If you format the key (ie keyScope) in the document template, then the variable that replaces the key will retain they key's formatting.

```
  //...trimmed previous code
  // Get document template, copy it as a new temp doc, and save the docs id
  var copyId = DocsList.getFileById(docTemplate)
  .makeCopy(docName)
  .getId();  

  //Open the temporary document and set it to a variable
  var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);

  //Get the documents body section
  var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

  //Replace place holder keys, in our google doc template
  copyBody.replaceText('keyline_item', line_item);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyDescr', descr);
  copyBody.replaceText('keyJobName', job_name);

  copyDoc.saveAndClose();



}
```

Although this is the only answer I know of that answers the original question, what the author is looking for is a way to preserve formatting (bold) in a variable that joins two values from different cells (with different formatting).  To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible to carry formatting from spreadsheets to documents, regardless of the number of variables because the keyReplace object is only composed of the raw text (or formula) that occupies the targeted cell or range where .getValues() is used.

If I'm wrong about this, I would appreciate someone correcting me, but since the author combines two adjacent cells into a single variable, and that is the answer he is seeking, I would think that it still wouldn't be possible to do as a single keyObject replacement in a template because two cells with different formatting are being merged into a single object in the script.  I know that you can get background and foreground colors, but you have to get those by R1C1 notation.  Are there other formatting options that can be captured from spreadsheets?

Either way, I'm going to leave this to the pros, because the only way I could see, from his source files, was to completely rewrite his document template and script, and that is not what the author of the question is looking for. I will leave my script above for people who may want to do something similar in the future.

Comment: Yes, that works, but the issue is that I only want one of the variables to be bold and not the other.  I have 2 variables (line_item and desc)  I want line_item to print in bold to the google doc.

Comment: Bold the keyLine_Item, but not keyDesc in your template.  Also, I'll look at template and script when I get home from work, but try that in meantime.

Comment: I think you'll have to see the document because...The script resides in the spreadsheet where there is the 2 variables(line_item,desc).  Then line_item and desc are put together in a variable textToDoc.  Then the script prints to the document by replacing keyJobScope with the variable textToDoc.  So I don't see a way to change just the line_item variable.  If I made a keyLineItem and keyDesc instead of keyJobScope, then how would I assemble LineItem next to Desc...

Comment: Following up on the comments, I eliminated the var that combined the line_item and descr vars into a single var (textToDoc), and then placed two keys on your template.  I bold formatted keyline_item and left keyDescr plain.  I modified the .replaceText ('keyJobScope', jobScope); line to replace the line_item key, and added a line to .replaceText('keyDescr', descr);  I tested and verified that this works as per your question.

See edited answer for correct code.  Look at your template document for the changes that I made there (removed unused key, added 2 new keys, formatted).

Comment: Thanks for the work you did.  However, it seems like it's only printing the last item from my spreadsheet.

Comment: Do you want all of the items on your sheet?  I can work on that really quick.  I'll only charge you an upvote on the answer :P

Comment: thoughtcrime, are you still there?  I haven't seen any progress in the last couple days...

Comment: Yeah, I am. I made a copy of everything, so you won't see anything until I get the template rebuilt.  I should be able to finish the template structure soon and then the code will follow soon thereafter.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you sure that the template is the better approach ? you could also analyze the SS row by row and reproduce each row in the doc using spreadsheet methods to get the style and doc method to set the style accordingly. (see this documentation, the "get" serie : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range

Comment: The initial problem space used a template with the joined variables. I'm not sure if OP had another idea otherwise.

Comment: What I ended up doing was put a script in the doc template that onOpen reformats the keys.  I will look at Serge's suggestion thou...